# OCR extraction from scans

Tags: ocr, text-extraction

I have been tasked by my university to digitise a whole bunch of historical data. These are old scans from books and my task would be to copy the data by hand.

I was wondering if I could use OCR in Python that would extract the data and create a CSV file. In the meantime I have encountered the problem that.

- sometimes bad readability of the numbers
- table lines are seen as characters: / ( )

By now I have tried Onenote character extraction and Excel 'read from image'. Both didn't go well.

So I'm wondering if anyone can recommend a package specifically for this data, or if you have tips and tricks for this task that would otherwise take me weeks. One example of the scans:

[image]

I need to extract the numbers on the from the image

### Edit

When using a slant correction first, this is the following result for Excel:

[image]

Comment: Could you apply a slant correction first, and then try using the OCR tools you are already using?

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion! I have already tried that, but it didnt work.

Comment: I suspect this might be off-topic because (a) it's not really a programming task, and (b) library recommendations are off-topic here. Could you find an OCR package and give it a go? That way you can show code and it becomes more solidly on-topic.

Comment: The other bit of feedback is that perhaps you could show your slant-corrected image before it is OCR scanned, but then that is also not a programming question (unless you are doing that in code). Maybe you could split up the question and get the slant correction right first? Assuming that is not code you could ask that on _Super User_ (one of the sister sites to Stack Exchange).